# Declaring a variable from grep in array Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I'm making a script that extracts a url from a tweet. In running the script and out putting it into an array it out putted about 30 urls only one of which is the correct one. So I used a grep with the first part of the url I wanted from the array and got the 'found it' output.

```
my $tco = "http://t.co";

if (grep /$tco/, @links) {
    print "found it\n";
}
```

I was wondering if I could takw that line what started with http://t.co and make that line into a variable ex:

```
$extracted_url = 'what I found in the array'
```

How would I go about doing this? Thank you in advance!, Brett

Comment: note that since you are looking for a constant string, you want to escape special characters in your regex:  `grep /\Q$tco/`.  Otherwise, the `.` will match any character, and your regex will match e.g. `http://tacobell.com`.  You are also looking for `http://t.co` anywhere in each link; if you mean to be looking only for links that start with that pattern, you need `grep /^\Q$tco/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
my @found = (grep /\Q$tco/, @links);
for my $url (@found) {
    print "found $url\n";
}
```

Comment: Thankd, it printed them (there's two) to the console how do I go about making those url's on the console into variables would I do something like $newvariable = my @found = (grep /$tco/, @links);
if (@found) {
    for my $url (@found) {
        print "found $url\n";
    }
}

Comment: The printing is only there to demonstrate the variables are being populated. Specifically, they are `$found[0]` and `$found[1]`. `$newvariable` makes no sense since it's one variable and there are two urls. But if you prefer, you can replace `$url` with `$newvariable` in tangent's code.